# Modern Hebrew alphabet pronunciation of י, ד, and ק?

Tags: pronunciation, hebrew

Most letters in the Hebrew alphabet have only one pronunciation, but there are a few with two potential pronunciations. I know that both are acceptable, **but how are Israeli kids taught to pronounce them these days in school?**

The letters are:

`ד` - dalet or daled?

`י` - yod or yud?

`ק` - kof or kuf?

Comment: Very good and non-broad question. That's also why I did a bounty for you, other than wanting to stop your frustration! :) :D <3

Comment: OK thanks! Hopefully an Israeli chimes in.

Comment: No problem. <3 enjoy your answers and good luck!

Comment: Just a note: I have asked questions before relating to how to pronounce 2 different Arabic letters & my question was flagged for not being relevant to language learning so be careful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PART 1: Survey of educated Israelis**

I got in touch with four very educated Israelis (all have Master's and/or PhD), and this is what they said:

1. Israeli #1: daled, yud, and kuf are the common pronunciations, and
   dalet, yod, kof are the "correct" ones.
2. Israeli #2: daled, yod, kuf are taught in school.
3. Israeli #3: daled, yud, and kuf are the common pronunciations, and
   dalet, yod, kof are the "correct" ones.
4. Israeli #4: "dalet is prescribed by the Academy and is most common, so no question there. The same for kuf. For yud I wasn't able to find the issue addressed by the Academy. They sometimes do that when there is no historic or rule-based reason to favor one form over the other. So I'll go with yud as it's by far more common among native speakers".

Taught-in-school consensus = 3 out of 4 **dalet**, 3 out of 4 **yod**, 2 out of 4 **kof**.

There is a difference of opinion, so clearly it's not 100% obvious. Thus I undertook a second phase of this research.

---

**PART 2: Online research**

I did some more research on my own by looking at the Hebrew wikipedia pages on these three letters:

- [Dalet](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93) (`דל"ת`) seems to be the official pronunciation of `ד`. Interestingly, `דל"ד` is not even listed as an option on the Hebrew page.
- [Yod](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99) (`יוֹד`) seems to be the official pronunciation of `י`, and `יוּד` is listed second.
- [Kof](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7) (`קוֹף`) seems to be the official pronunciation of `ק`, and `קוּף` is listed second.

---

**Summary**

In summary, it seems that **dalet** is the least ambiguously most common and correct, thus it is the official one, as well as **yod** and **kof**, and these are the "correct" pronunciations taught in school. But many/most commonly say **yud** and **kuf**, in addition to **dalet**. The good news is you can pronounce these three with either variation and no one will blink an eye.

Comment: You missed one: צ, which is officially "tzadi" but is sometimes pronounced "tzadik".

Comment: I didn't include that letter because that's just a Yiddish variation/influence.